# QR with link and more info

Tags: web, hyperlink, qr-code

I´m trying to find a way to put a web link in a QR code, but with more info in the final, so when I try to capture with a Standard QR Reader it will jump to my link, but when I read it with my Android app, I will take just the data that I need.

EG - If I want to go to Facebook and have another String in the link.

www.facebook.com+hello

I just need to know how to encode the link to make this work.

Thanks!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your additional info at the end of the link after an `#`, but if the website you linked use `#` with parameters you would be out of luck.

Example:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/#myadditionalinfo=test